# Is it possible to have windows autocomplete custom commands?

Tags: autocomplete, console, customization

I'm running Console2, which I believe is just an interface to windows cmd

I have a custom batch file that does most of my dirty work for me, but there are lot of commands in it now. Is there a way I can get a tap autocomplete working for it in the windows command prompt?

For example: my script is called rob.bat and it takes in a various number of arguments

It'd like to type rob set{Tab} and then have it cycle through

setup_envvars
setup_userprefs
setup_whateverothersetupscriptsIhave

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would love to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Console2 has no special provisions for tab completion and instead relies on the program running within it to provide such features. Picture Console2 as little more than something that runs a console program hidden somewhere, regularly polls that hidden window for changes, and forwards all input to that window; this is, in essence, what's happening.

Note that Console2 does nothing special with `cmd`. You can run any shell within it. As for customizing tab completion, `cmd` offers nothing of that sort. You may be able to change this by installing [clink](https://github.com/mridgers/clink), which has extension points for Lua code. Another option would be PowerShell, which has customizable tab completion out of the box, either by wrapping your program in a [function that provides the necessary parameters](https://foxdeploy.com/2017/01/13/adding-tab-completion-to-your-powershell-functions/), or by writing a custom `TabExpansion` or `TabExpansion2` function.